# Why do do HDMI to DisplayPort adapters come with a USB charging cable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, adapter

I've been looking for an adapter that will allow me to use my Samsung monitor with my macbook. I bought a docking station with two HDMI ports, while the monitor uses DisplayPort. Because I also use this monitor with a Windows laptop, I already have a DisplayPort to USB-c adapter.

With my setup, I have 1 available USB-c port, hence buying the docking station. My plan was to buy an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter that would allow me to quickly switch between docking stations based on the laptop I'm using.

However, it's been impossible to find an adapter that isn't DisplayPort to HDMI. The ones I have found come with a USB charging cable. I've seen listings say that the cable needs to be connected to a power supply. Why is that? If Display Port to HDMI (Male to Female) is possible without charging, what makes the opposite not possible?

(I'm unable to paste the pictures I had)

Comment: Please check your 'directions' as written in your question. Signals go **from** > **to**. There is no such thing as a DisplayPort **to** USB-C connector, which makes me suspicious of all your other label directions.

Comment: you might be right. I reversed the order because displayport to hdmi results aren't what I want.

Basically, the monitor is displayport. My mac is hdmi. I want a cable that sends video from my mac to the external monitor

Comment: [This](https://www.tempest-av.com/single-post/2019/02/07/hdmi-to-displayport-and-displayport-to-hdmi-conversion-explained) article will explain some of the *why*.  I found it quite enlightening.  Apparently, DisplayPort cables don't use pin 20 (3.3v) because it might cause a short.  This might very well have something to do with the external power.. read for yourself though.  The article is quite well written.

Comment: should have included that in the description. I did read it but couldn't fully understand it. But with mokubai's answer, it makes much more sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because while Displayport transmitters, as built into a graphics card, are capable of "falling back" to HDMI mode the same cannot be said about HDMI ports "upgrading" to DisplayPort. DisplayPort is "backwards compatible" but HDMI is not "forwards compatible" with DP.

HDMI is a "bunch of pixels" transmission protocol.

DisplayPort data is [transmitted very differently to HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort):

> It is the first display interface to rely on packetized data transmission, a form of digital communication found in technologies such as Ethernet, USB, and PCI Express

As such for DisplayPort to transmit HDMI all it has to do is to stop "packetising" the data, i.e. the packetizing system switches to pass-through, and switch transmitter electronics mode slightly. For HDMI to begin transmitting DisplayPort it would need an extra stage to encapsulate the data.

As a result HDMI to DisplayPort adaptors require active electronics in them and there you hit another problem. HDMI does not output power on the connector, so you need a power supply for the chip that collects up HDMI data and puts out DisplayPort packets.

That is what the USB connector is doing. It is powering the active electronics in the adaptor.

This is the key difference between "active" and "passive" adaptors. Active adaptors have electronics that needs power for the electronics to work, passive adaptors simply shuffle the electrical signals around and let the host work out what kind of output it needs to use.

There are *some* active cables that can leech power from the PC port (I believe VGA might output *just* enough power on each pin for some modern electronics, but don't rely on it) but if your adaptor has a power port then you should use it or expect unreliable results.

Comment: It's not strictly true that HDMI does not carry power. It's just that it's not a lot: 0.25 W. It's enough for many HDMI-to-VGA-adapters I have seen.

Comment: @DanielB I can only find references to 5V@50mA [such as here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/could-hdmi-be-potentially-used-as-a-power-supply-alternative-for-smartphones) 50mA might enough for *something* but it's not much. You might be able to source a bit more current from other lines, but it's not intended and could result in out of spec signals that could degrade the video. [HDMI 2.1 Cable Power](https://www.hdmi.org/spec21sub/cablepower) that allows 300mA is a relatively recent addition (Q3/4 2020) and should not be expected to be supplied as standard.

Comment: I believe it's originally for powering DDC chips (containing the EDID). And yes, this is what I was referring to.